# Integrate $\int_c \frac{dz}{z^2 + 4}$ and $\int_c \sqrt z dz $

Tags: complex-analysis

> (a) Integrate $\displaystyle \int_c \frac{dz}{z^2 + 4}$ along the line $x + y = 1$ in the direction of increasing $x$.
>
> (b) Evaluate $\displaystyle \int_{-2 - 2 \sqrt 3 i}^{-2 + 2 \sqrt 3i}  \sqrt z dz $ along the straight line path if we choose that branch of $z^{1/2}$ such that $z^{1/2} = 1$ for $z = 1$

The answers are given as $\pi/2$ and $32/3$. For first I tried to substitue $x = t, y = 1 - t$ and integrated from $-\infty \to \infty $ but I can't get the answer.

For second I tried to integrate it directly, as well as putting $z = 4 e^{i (\theta + 2 \pi)}$ but can't seem to get the answer.

Help!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second problem is difficult because if you blindly evaluate the integral without being sensitive to the branch cut across the negative real axis (necessary because of the demand that $\sqrt{1} = 1$), you get

$$\int_{4 e^{-i 2 \pi/3}}^{4 e^{i 2 \pi/3}} dz \sqrt{z} = \frac{2}{3} 4^{3/2} \left (e^{i \pi} - e^{-i \pi} \right ) = 0$$

To do this integral correctly, you need to add $2 \pi$ to the argument of the upper integration limit because the transition across the branch cut introduces that discontinuity.  Therefore we have

$$\int_{4 e^{-i 2 \pi/3}}^{e^{i (2 \pi/3 + 2 \pi)}} dz \sqrt{z} =  \frac{2}{3} 4^{3/2} \left (e^{i( \pi + 3 \pi)} - e^{-i \pi} \right ) = 2 \frac{2}{3} 2^3 = \frac{32}{3}$$

Comment: yes, i was getting zero!!

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem, you are doing fine and the integral is

$$ \displaystyle \int_c \frac{dz}{z^2 + 4} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(1-i)dt}{(t+i(1-t))^2 + 4}=\frac{\pi}{2}. $$

If you do not want to work out the integral by hand, you can ask Maple or Mathematica to evaluate it.

Comment: Eh ... I tried the same but i couldn't get the desired result. could you elaborate it a bit?

Comment: Expand and then complete the square in the denominator and use some substitution.

Comment: can't I simply use $\frac{1}{2i} \ln \left( \frac{1 - iz}{1 + iz}\right)$ fomula (that's were it got complicated)? okay that's for the hint .. I'll try that. Could you also help me with second probelm?